# Maven deploy + source classifiers

Tags: maven, maven-source-plugin

I'm trying to deploy a Maven artifact with a classifier. Since I need both the sources and the JAR (I'm using it from GWT), I would like to get `artifact-version-classifier.jar` and `artifact-version-classifier-sources.jar`. However, it works fine with the compiled JAR, but fails with the sources (the output sources JAR has a wrong name).

This is the configuration that I have so far:

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <classifier>prod</classifier>
    </configuration>
</plugin>

<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>attach-sources</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>jar</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <finalName>${project.build.finalName}-prod</finalName>
    </configuration>
</plugin>

<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <classifier>prod</classifier>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

And this is the output I'm getting for `mvn deploy`:

```
Uploading: http://juicebox:8080/archiva/repository/snapshots//ar/com/nubing/afip-connector/1.0-SNAPSHOT/afip-connector-1.0-SNAPSHOT-prod.jar
237K uploaded  (afip-connector-1.0-SNAPSHOT-prod.jar)
```

But this one has a wrong name:

```
Uploading: http://juicebox:8080/archiva/repository/snapshots//ar/com/nubing/afip-connector/1.0-SNAPSHOT/afip-connector-1.0-SNAPSHOT-sources.jar
228K uploaded  (afip-connector-1.0-SNAPSHOT-sources.jar)
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Sadly, attaching a source JAR with an arbitrary classifier is not supported by the source plugin.  When the source artifact is [attached](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-source-plugin/xref/org/apache/maven/plugin/source/AbstractSourceJarMojo.html#300), the classifier is [hardcoded](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-source-plugin/xref/org/apache/maven/plugin/source/SourceJarNoForkMojo.html#63) (as of version 2.1.2 of source plugin).

You can work around the issue by getting the source plugin to generate the JAR but not attach, and attach it with the [build helper plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/build-helper-maven-plugin/index.html)'s [attach artifact](http://www.mojohaus.org/build-helper-maven-plugin/attach-artifact-mojo.html) goal.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.7</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>attach-source-jar</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>attach-artifact</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <artifacts>
                    <artifact>
                        <file>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}-prod-sources.jar</file>
                        <type>jar</type>
                        <classifier>prod-sources</classifier>
                    </artifact>
                </artifacts>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: @prunge this is fixed in version 2.2

Answer (score 4):

Used the same workaround as prunge for this. But that's no longer necessary. This is a [reported Bug](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MSOURCES-50) that was fixed in version 2.2 in June 2012: Just set the property `<classifier>`. Tested with 2.2.1 .

Answer (score 1):

A bit more of an updated answer, using sources and javadoc

```
<maven.javadoc.version>3.0.1</maven.javadoc.version>
<maven.source.version>3.0.1</maven.source.version>


<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${maven.source.version}</version>
    <configuration>
        <classifier>jre10-sources</classifier>
    </configuration>
</plugin>



 <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${maven.javadoc.version}</version>
    <configuration>
        <classifier>jre10-javadoc</classifier>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Thisi is the only correct solution which should be accepted as a SOLUTION.