# How to deploy the sources file with the jar using deploy:deploy-file

Tags: java, maven, deployment, jar, maven-source-plugin

I have the following plugins for creating a `-sources.jar` and deploying a specific named jar to a repository.

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>attach-sources</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>jar</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.5</version>
    <configuration>
        <version>${project.version}-r${buildNumber}</version>
        <classifier>${env}</classifier>
        <packaging>jar</packaging>
        <file>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}.jar</file>
        <url>${artifactory.url}/libs-release-local</url>
        <repositoryId>artifactory.digiterre.com</repositoryId>
        <pomFile>${project.basedir}/pom.xml</pomFile>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

I wish to deploy the `*-sources.jar` at the same time. I have tried adding a second file entry and even a second deploy plugin. I seem to get one or other file deployed.

Is it possible to deploy both in one pass using `deploy:deploy-file` or will I have to set up a second team city build just to deploy the sources?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4725668/how-to-deploy-snapshot-with-sources-and-javadoc ?

Comment: I have looked at that post and tried the suggestions. Neither work as I am deploying a file with specific classifier. Also jar-no-fork does not work Maven throws an error.

Comment: It's a bit dirty, but maybe use an Ant task from Maven that executes a deploy from the command line?

Comment: I am not using any pom.xml file , from jenkin how I will pass the version number dynamically.Suggest me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you use `maven-source-plugin`, the generated jar will automatically attach to project artifact (default setting for [this](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-source-plugin/jar-no-fork-mojo.html#attach) parameter is 'true') and if you execute `deploy` it will be deployed along with it. Alas, no need for separate configuration of deploy plugin.

Unfortunately, you cannot add classifier (`${env}` in your case) to sources jar. That is why I'd use the following configuration:

```xml
...
<artifactId>com.pie.mash.repo.mince-${env}</artifactId>
<version>1.18-r${buildNumber}</version>
...
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.1.2</version>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <goals>
            <goal>jar-no-fork</goal>
          </goals>
        </execution>
      </executions>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```

Also, I've found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8499266/maven-deploy-source-classifiers) question on SO. You can use the workaround suggested there.

Comment: using 2.1.2 version explicitly does not throw the error I was getting previously.

Comment: However, the sources still do not get deployed using this example.

Comment: @Yoztastic You should invoke `mvn clean deploy`. And, as I've already mentioned, there is no need for separate configuration of deploy plugin.

Comment: removing the maven-deploy-plugin altogether fails to resolve dependencies to maven-deploy-plugin v2.4. Leaving the existing one in but removing the configuration section results in uploading jar and sources jar but with the r* and $env sections missing. It is odd because in target the correct files get created with the correct names.

Comment: @Yoztastic Can you provide a log file of `mvn deploy`?

Comment: [https://docs.google.com/document/d/1A4BoVAn9rLqvK4ZUCTJ8q6axGMRAYUWAxMHZLcgVN70/edit?pli=1](log.txt) note **com.pie.mash.repo.mince-1.18-r5135-pie_gravy.jar** is the desired name **com.pie.mash.repo.mince-1.18-sources.jar** gets uploaded

Comment: this will not work as **r${buildNumber}** will not be known in the context of  **<version>1.18-r${buildNumber}</version>** it only becomes available later.

Comment: Sadly for you, it won't work then. Take a close look at log you provided above - `com.pie.mash.repo.mince-1.18.jar` gets deployed. This is because Maven takes coordinates from project and in project you have `<version>1.18</version>`.

Comment: so strange that it has no trouble copying the correct files to the target dir but cant upload them to Artifactory. Really disappointing must have spent over a day on this and what should have been a small incremental step has gone nowhere. Thanks for your persistence.

Answer (score 5):

We can use `deploy:deploy-file` to upload multiple JARs (sources, tests, docs) along side main JAR artifact. We just need to supply that additional piece of information to `deploy:deploy-file` plugin call. The additions are indicated in bold in below command:

> mvn deploy:deploy-file
> -Dfile=helloWorld.jar
> -Durl=https://localhost/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/
> -DrepositoryId=snapshot
> **-Dfiles=helloWorld-6.4.1.3.SNAPSHOT-sources.jar,helloWorld-6.4.1.3.SNAPSHOT-tests.jar**
> **-Dtypes=jar,jar** **-Dclassifiers=sources,tests** 
> -DgroupId=com
> -DartifactId=helloWorld
> -Dversion=6.4.1.3.SNAPSHOT
> -Dpackaging=jar
> -Dpomfile=pom.xml

- We need to specify list of files separated by commas.
- We need to specify the types of those additional files.
- We need to add classifier information for those additional files.

Comment: please format the answer properly. For additional details, please check [answer]

Answer (score 1):

`mvn deploy:deploy-file` only deploys a single artifact.  Instead you can use `mvn deploy` (which invokes `mvn deploy:deploy`) to deploy the artifact, its pom along with the attached artifacts (like source and javadoc).   Refer to the goals overview of [maven deploy plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/index.html).

Comment: I am using deploy:deploy-file url=http://repo.xxx.xxx.com/content/repositories/peroo-snapshots/
repositoryId=peroo-snapshots
groupId=com.xxx.ist.curo.testtalentClient
artifactId=pet_client_osx
version=${CLIENT_VERSIONCITEST}.0-SNAPSHOT
packaging=tar
classifier=Rev_${SVN_REVISION}
file=$WORKSPACE/CWave3/TalentOSX/build/Release/Talent.app.tar

Comment: CLIENT_VERSIONCITEST environment variable should change every time, but its not working on jenkins.