# Ensure test jars are named correctly

Tags: java, maven, build

I'm setting up our system to do dual building for different versions of java artifacts based on the jdk used.  There are 4 jars to build:  artifact, artifact-tests, artifact-sources, and artifact-test-sources.  Here is the output of the build

```
[INFO] Installing /Users/carlos/workspace/svn/Libraries/artifact-name/trunk/pom.xml to /Users/carlos/.m2/repository/package-path/artifact-name/1.0.8-SNAPSHOT/artifact-name-1.0.8-SNAPSHOT.pom
[INFO] Installing /Users/carlos/workspace/svn/Libraries/path/artifact-name-1.0.8-SNAPSHOT-java6.jar to /Users/carlos/.m2/repository/package-path/artifact-name/1.0.8-SNAPSHOT/artifact-name-1.0.8-SNAPSHOT-java6.jar
[INFO] Installing /Users/carlos/workspace/svn/Libraries/path/artifact-name-1.0.8-SNAPSHOT-sources.jar to /Users/carlos/.m2/repository/package-path/artifact-name/1.0.8-SNAPSHOT/artifact-name-1.0.8-SNAPSHOT-sources.jar
[INFO] Installing /Users/carlos/workspace/svn/Libraries/path/artifact-name-1.0.8-SNAPSHOT-test-sources.jar to /Users/carlos/.m2/repository/package-path/artifact-name/1.0.8-SNAPSHOT/artifact-name-1.0.8-SNAPSHOT-test-sources.jar
[INFO] Installing /Users/carlos/workspace/svn/Libraries/path/artifact-name-1.0.8-SNAPSHOT-tests.jar to /Users/carlos/.m2/repository/package-path/artifact-name/1.0.8-SNAPSHOT/artifact-name-1.0.8-SNAPSHOT-tests.jar
```

You can see the main artifact is built with java6 and has the appropriate classifier.  I'm assuming the `test` classifier is overwriting the `java6` classifier, but I'm unsure.  Is there a way to get it to be named explicitly for both tests and the jdk?  Something like -1.0.8-SNAPSHOT-tests-java6.jar.  I'de like to refrain from doing manual changes to the `final.name` if possible and just use stock functionality like I did for the main artifact.

Here are the relevant parts of the pom.

```
<build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven.jar.version}</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven.compiler.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${jdk.version}</source>
                    <target>${jdk.version}</target>
                    <forceJavacCompilerUse>true</forceJavacCompilerUse>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven.source.version}</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.9</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>analyze</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>analyze-only</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <failOnWarning>true</failOnWarning>
                        <ignoreNonCompile>true</ignoreNonCompile>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <!--<configuration>-->
            <!--<skip>true</skip>-->
            <!--</configuration>-->
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>${jdk.version}</source>
                <target>${jdk.version}</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>jar</goal>
                        <goal>test-jar</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <classifier>${jdk.version.display}</classifier>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>test-jar</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>java6</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
            <jdk>1.6</jdk>
        </activation>
        <properties>
            <jdk.version>1.6</jdk.version>
            <jdk.version.display>java6</jdk.version.display>
        </properties>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>java7</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
            <jdk>1.7</jdk>
        </activation>
        <properties>
            <jdk.version>1.7</jdk.version>
            <jdk.version.display>java7</jdk.version.display>
        </properties>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>java8</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
            <jdk>1.8</jdk>
        </activation>
        <properties>
            <jdk.version>1.8</jdk.version>
            <jdk.version.display>java8</jdk.version.display>
        </properties>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `-sources`, `-tests` and `-test-sources` JARs are themselves using classifiers. So e.g. in the case of `sources`, you would need to override the maven-source-plugin's `<classifier>` configuration option (see also [Maven deploy + source classifiers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8499266)). I doubt that doing this is well tested across all the tool sets that consume `-sources` artifacts. For example, will Eclipse still download the sources for your `java6` classifier artifact if you call the classifier `java6-sources`? And what about the `tests`, `test-sources` and (if you need it later) `javadoc` classifiers—will you complicate your POM further to generate all of those differently as well? Perhaps you could make it all work, but rather than trod down that path, it would be easier to simply use two different artifactIds, one for `java6` and one for `java7`, and leave classifiers out of the equation.